# Issue in controlling 2 clock schedules in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a button. On pressing it, i want to invoke one action after 5 seconds once and then 2nd action infinite times after every 1 second. But i need to start action 2nd only after action one completes.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:            
    Button:
        id:timer1
        text: 'click me'
        on_press: root.val()
''')
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.my_callback_timer1, 5)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback_timer2, 1)
    def my_callback_timer1(self, interval):
        print "5 sec code executed"
    def my_callback_timer2(self, interval):
        print "1 sec code executed"


sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This gives o/p as:

```
1 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
5 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
...
...
```

and what i need is:

```
5 sec code executed
(wait 5 sec)
1 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
1 sec code executed
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule the second clock in the first callback:

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.my_callback_timer1, 5)

    def my_callback_timer1(self, interval):
        print "5 sec code executed"
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback_timer2, 1)
    def my_callback_timer2(self, interval):
        print "1 sec code executed"
```

Comment: thanks...i already figured it out...same way as your reply... :)